# How do I set parameters when using "forward:/"

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, vue.js, forward

I have the following Spring code...

```
@GetMapping("/error")
public String getError(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    ...
    return "forward:/";
}
@GetMapping("")
String get( ){ return "index"; }
```

My VueJS router looks like this...

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Viewport,
        children: [
            {
                path:'/',
                component: Content
            },
            {
                path:'/error',
                component: Error
            }
        ]
    }
];
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes: routes
});
```

But now I want to pass the type like this...

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Viewport,
        children: [
            {
                path:'/',
                component: Content
            },
            {
                path:'/error',
                component: Error,
                children: [
                    {
                        path:"/auth",
                        component: AuthError
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

So in this case the url should be `/error/auth`. But I also want to take it a step further and provide a message like this `/error/auth?message=blahblahblah`

How would I add these values to the URL?

Comment: Why not `path:'/error/:module'`. Then you can grab `this.$route.params.module` to determine what module the error belongs to, and `this.$route.query.message` to get the actual message. This matches `/error/:module?message=<anything>` as you indicated

Comment: I am doing something similar. My problem was more around having to create Java code for each endpoint so I need to forward each one. I was hoping for something less tedious